# React Pluggable - Component isn't removed from the DOM on uninstallation of a plugin

Tags: reactjs

TodoPlugin.tsx which renders the component on its installation.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { IPlugin, PluginStore } from "react-pluggable";
import Todos from "../components/todo/Todos";
import MainTodo from "../components/todo/MainTodo";

class TodoPlugin implements IPlugin {
  namespace = "Todo";

  pluginStore!: PluginStore;

  getPluginName(): string {
    return `${this.namespace}@1.0.0`;
  }
  getDependencies(): string[] {
    return [];
  }

  init(pluginStore: PluginStore): void {
    this.pluginStore = pluginStore;
  }

  TodoComponent = () => {
    return <MainTodo />;
  };

  activate(): void {
    this.pluginStore.executeFunction(
      "Renderer.add",
      "Todo.todos",
      this.TodoComponent
    );
  }
  deactivate(): void {
    this.pluginStore.removeFunction("Todo.todos");
  }
}

export default TodoPlugin;
```

Test.tsx, which is installing and uninstalling the Todo plugin on button click.

```
const onLogin = (event: any) => {
    pluginStore.install("Todo");
  };

  const onLogout = (event: any) => {
   pluginStore.uninstall("Todo");
  };
return (
    <>
      <button id="login" onClick={onLogin}>
        Login
      </button>

      <button
        id="logout" onClick={onLogout}
      >
        Logout
      </button>


      <Renderer placement={"Todo.todos"} />
    </>
  );
```

On clicking the Logout button, the component with the placement Todo.todos didn't get removed and if I click the Login button again, a new Component is created and rendered after the first component.

Comment: Did you tried remove you node_modules and run `yarn or npm install` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your deactivate function, you have not removed component from the Renderer. Instead of removing "Todo.todo", you can remove the component by the following snippet:

```
this.pluginStore.executeFunction(
      "Renderer.remove",
      "Todo.todos",
);
```